# mysql batch insertion - large number of records

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, batch-processing, bulkinsert

I am trying to insert multiple records to MySQL table in single go.

FYI: My tech stack is Nodejs+MySQL (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)

What I am currently doing is:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

The problem with my above solution is that when I have around 50k records, the MySQL buffer explodes.

For that I changed

```
max_allowed_packet = 1000MB
```

But I am sure that is not a proper solution. I am looking for the best & optimized workaround possible in this scenario.

Any clues or hints would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: *I am sure that is not a proper solution.* I see no reason for such a conclusion.

Comment: @Akina I am thinking in my head, something regarding insertion in chunks

Comment: *The problem with my above solution is that when I have around 50k records* You may insert by chunks (for example, 10k rows per query). But session setting adjust is a norma. So the solution with `SET SESSION max_allowed_packet = ...` is safe.

Comment: CVS will be not shorter or will be shorter slightly - so it makes no sense. You may fing some another way - for example, save this CSV to file and load it via LOAD DATA - but I do not think that this is reasonable, and it contradicts your framework usage. *Dont you think that we are blind guessing the size of max_allowed_packet?* You may set this session setting to its allowed upper size - this does not effect another sessions or the server itself.

Answer (score 1):

For many reasons (you encountered one of them), I break up batch inserts into clumps of 100 or 1000 rows at a time.  That will be within 1% of the same speed, while avoiding lots of problems.

Comment: Yeah doing batches is actually good for memory consumption optimization. It might be more performant to do 1000 rows in a batch then 10k rows.

Comment: @Nux - 1K probably has 1% overhead; 10K might have 0.1% overhead, but would involve more/bigger mallocs, etc, so might actually run slower.

Comment: Yes, that and when you run things in parallel (and you do on the web) the you might get whole lot of different side effects. BTW. Not specific to MySQL, also true in MS SQL, but batches are created a bit differently.

Comment: @Nux - When doing similar things _independently_ in different connections, small batches leads to less chance of deadlock because each chunk runs faster.